# Reshaped views in Parallel Colt

Tags: numpy, reshape, colt

In numpy, there is a `flatten` operation which allows you to, for example, flatten a `m x n` matrix down to an array of `mn` elements, and a `reshape` operations which goes in the opposite direction.  Much of the time this can be done with a view, without creating a copy of the original data.

Does such a capability exist in Parallel Colt, the Java matrix library?  I have not been able to find one.  There is a `reshape` method on one-dimensional matrices, but it appears to create copies.